# Looping a process for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA and have ran into what I believe should be a simple fix.  Below is code that I am using to create temp tables.  The code is functional and working as intended, however, I would like to add another level. I want to build a loop that repeats this process for multiple rows in the RsP! recordset.  So if I have 3 rows in the rsP tables I would like to create these record 3 separate times. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated, I have hit a brick wall even though I am sure the answer is right in front of me.  Thank You!

```
    Do Until (x = colCount)


    With rsNewRedacted

        .AddNew

            !A0 = rsP![Redacted ID]

            If (Right(rsP![Redacted / Redacted Name], 1) = "-") Then
                !A1 = Left(rsP![Redacted / Redacted Name], Len(rsP![Redacted / Redacted Name]) - 1) 
            Else
                !A1 = rsP![Redacted / Redacted Name]                                                
            End If

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("01.06")
            !A5 = removeSpecialInclSpace(rsI("Col" & x))

            !A6 = Left(rsP![Redacted ID], 2)                                                     
            !A9 = rsP![MCC]                                                                     

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("05.02")
            p0502 = rsI("Col" & x)
            !A10 = removeSpecial(rsI("Col" & x))                                                

            !A14 = rsDefRedacted![A14]                                                           
            !A16 = rsDefRedacted![A16]                                                           
            !A23 = rsDefRedacted![A23]                                                           

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.12")                                              
            p0212 = removeSpecial(rsI("Col" & x))
            !A27 = p0212

            '!A27 = rsDefRedacted![A27]                                                           

            !A30 = rsDefRedacted![A30]                                                           

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("01.16")
            !A53 = rsI("Col" & x)                                                               

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.09")                                              
            !A56 = rsI("Col" & x)
            !A80 = rsI("Col" & x)

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.10")                                              
            !A57 = rsI("Col" & x)
            !A81 = rsI("Col" & x)

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.11")
            !A58 = rsI("Col" & x)                                                               
            !A82 = rsI("Col" & x)                                                               

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.14")
            !A59 = rsI("Col" & x)                                                               

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("01.19")
            ee = rsI("Col" & x)                                                                 

            If (Left(ee, 1) = "Y") Then
                !A71 = "Y"
            Else
                !A71 = "N"
            End If

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.13")
            !A75 = rsI("Col" & x)                                                               


            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("07.13")
            p0713 = rsI("Col" & x)

            If (Left(p0713, 3) <> "n/a") And (p0713 <> "none") And (p0713 <> "no") Then         
                !A87 = p0713
            End If

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("09.21")
            p0921 = rsI("Col" & x)

            If (Left(p0921, 1) = "y") Then                                                      
                !A99 = "Y"
            End If

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("03.19")                                              
            p0319 = rsI("Col" & x)
            !A119 = p0319

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("03.19")
            !A119 = removeSpecial(rsI("Col" & x))                                                         

            rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("01.16")

            If (p0116 = "AUTO") Then
                rsI.AbsolutePosition = c.Item("02.25")
                p0225 = rsI("Col" & x)
                'A138 = removeSpecialInclSpace(p0225)
                A138 = p0225
            End If

        .Update

    End With
```

Comment: What Office product is this running in?  Excel, Word, Access?

Comment: Access, sorry that I didn't mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from your code you presumably already know how to open a recordset, you can iterate over the records in your recordset using a framework such as:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyTable")

If Not rst.EOF Then ' If our recordset contains some records
    rst.MoveFirst ' Move the cursor to the first record in the set
    Do Until rst.EOF ' Do the following until we have reached the end of the recordset

        ' Do your thing

        rst.MoveNext ' Move the cursor to the next record in the recordset
    Loop
Else
    ' else the recordset was empty
End If
```

Comment: @RC94 You're most welcome! Please mark my answer as the solution if it answered your question, so that the question is marked as resolved - thanks!